# Does the continuation + tail recursion trick actually trade stack space for heap space?

Tags: optimization, f#, functional-programming, tail-recursion, continuations

There is this CPS trick in functional programming to take a non-tail-recursive function and rewrite it in continuation passing style (CPS), thus trivially making it tail-recursive. A lot of questions actually cover this, like

- https://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2008/04/05/catamorphisms-part-one/
- [F#: In which memory area is the continuation stored: stack or heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34363645/f-in-which-memory-area-is-the-continuation-stored-stack-or-heap)
- [why do continuations avoid stackoverflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746230/why-do-continuations-avoid-stackoverflow)

Take some example

```
let rec count n = 
    if n = 0
      then 0
      else 1 + count (n - 1)

let rec countCPS n cont =
    if n = 0
      then cont 0
      else countCPS (n - 1) (fun ret -> cont (ret + 1))
```

The first version of `count` will accumulate stack frames in each recursive call, producing a stack overflow at around `n = 60000` on my computer.

The idea of the CPS trick is that the `countCPS` implementation is tail-recursive, so that the computation

```
let f = countCPS 60000
```

will actually be optimized to run as a loop and work without problems. Instead of stack frames, the continuation to be run will accumulate in every step, but this is an honest object on the heap where memory doesn't cause problems. **So the CPS style is said to trade stack space for heap space. But I'm skeptical it does even do that.**

Here's why: Evaluating the computation by actually running the continuation as `countCPS 60000 (fun x -> x)` blows my stack! Each call

```
countCPS (n - 1) (fun ret -> cont (ret + 1))
```

generates a new continuation closure from the old one and running it involves one function application. So when evaluating `countCPS 60000 (fun x -> x)`, we invoke a nested sequence of 60000 closures, and even though their data lies on the heap, we have function applications nontheless, so there are the stack frames again.

Let's dive into the generated code, disassembled into C#

For `countCPS`, we get

```
public static a countCPS<a>(int n, FSharpFunc<int, a> cont)
{
    while (n != 0)
    {
        int arg_1B_0 = n - 1;
        cont = new Program<a>.countCPS@10(cont);
        n = arg_1B_0;
    }
    return cont.Invoke(0);
}
```

There we go, tail recursion actually got optimized away. However, the closure class looks like

```
internal class countCPS@10<a> : FSharpFunc<int, a>
{
    public FSharpFunc<int, a> cont;

    internal countCPS@10(FSharpFunc<int, a> cont)
    {
        this.cont = cont;
    }

    public override a Invoke(int ret)
    {
        return this.cont.Invoke(ret + 1);
    }
}
```

So running the outermost closure will cause it to `.Invoke` its child closure, then it's child closure again and again ... **We really have 60000 nested function calls again.**

So I don't see how the continuation trick is actually able to do what's being advertized.

Now we could argue that the `this.cont.Invoke` is sort of a tail call again, so it doesn't need a stack frame. Does .NET perform this kind of optimization? What about more complicated examples like

```
let rec fib_cps n k = match n with
  | 0 | 1 -> k 1
  | n -> fib_cps (n-1) (fun a -> fib_cps (n-2) (fun b -> k (a+b)))
```

At least we would have to argue why we can optimize away the nested function calls captured in the continuation.

---

## Edit

```
    interface FSharpFunc<A, B>
    {
        B Invoke(A arg);
    }

    class Closure<A> : FSharpFunc<int, A>
    {
        public FSharpFunc<int, A> cont;

        public Closure(FSharpFunc<int, A> cont)
        {
            this.cont = cont;
        }

        public A Invoke(int arg)
        {
            return cont.Invoke(arg + 1);
        }
    }

    class Identity<A> : FSharpFunc<A, A>
    {
        public A Invoke(A arg)
        {
            return arg;
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FSharpFunc<int, int> computation = new Identity<int>();

        for(int n = 10; n > 0; --n)
            computation = new Closure<int>(computation);

        Console.WriteLine(computation.Invoke(0));
    }
```

To be even more precise, we model the closure that the CPS style-function builds up in C#.

Clearly, the data lie on the heap. However, evaluating `computation.Invoke(0)` results in a cascade of nested `Invoke`s to the child closures. Just put a break point on `Identity.Invoke` and look at the stack trace! So how does the built-up computation trade stack- for heap space if it in fact heavily uses both?

Comment: How are you compiling and running your code?  `countCPS 60000 (fun x -> x)` works correctly for me.  And yes, the fact that the body of the lambda passed to the recursive call to `countCPS` is itself a tail call does matter!

Comment: Also note that disassembling to C# obscures whether a call such as the one to `cont.Invoke` is made with or without the IL `tail.` prefix, since C# syntax has no way to represent such a concept (to my knowledge the C# compiler will never emit a `tail.` prefix).  You're better off looking at the raw IL.

Comment: Your edit misses the point - there is no C# equivalent to the F# code, precisely because C# does not apply tail call optimization!  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2011/07/08/tail-calls-in-fsharp.aspx for a bit more on how to recognize tail calls in IL.

Comment: @kvb: Interesting, does it happen generically that whenever I rewrite a function in CPS, the accumulating calls can be tail-call-eliminated, or just for special easy cases?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I'll have a look at the IL.

Comment: Continuation passing style is less a trick to mimic tail recursion, but rather a fully-fledged concept of control flow. CPS is contrary to direct style, on which (tail) recursion is based on. Since CPS has more expressive power than recursion, you can do a lot more with it. By giving up the call stack, control flow shifts from outside within the functions. In this way it can be determined dynamically at runtime which function is to be called next.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a number of concepts here.

For a tail-recursive function, the compiler can optimize it into a loop and so it does not need any stack or heap space. You can rewrite your `count` function into a simple tail-recursive function by writing:

```
let rec count acc n = 
   if n = 0
      then acc
      else count (acc + 1) (n - 1)
```

This will be compiled into a method with a `while` loop that makes no recursive calls.

Continuations are generally needed when a function *cannot* be written as tail-recursive. Then you need to keep some state *either* on the stack *or* on the heap. Ignoring the fact that `fib` can be written more efficiently, the naïve recursive implementation would be:

```
let fib n = 
  if n <= 1 then 1
  else (fib (n-1)) + (fib (n-2))
```

This needs *stack* space to remember what needs to happen after the first recursive call returns the result (we then need to call the other recursive call and add the results). Using continuations, you can turn this into heap-allocated functions:

```
let fib n cont = 
  if n <= 1 then cont 1
  else fib (n-1) (fun r1 -> 
         fib (n-2) (fun r2 -> cont (r1 + r2))
```

This allocates one continuation (function value) for each recursive call, but it is tail-recursive so it will not exhaust the available stack space.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the concepts, but I know these and this doesn't quite address my question. I see how `fib` is tail recursive, so calling `fib n` is fine. My question, however is, why does evaluating `fib n (fun x -> x)` not amount to evaluating a huge delayed computation that consists out of deeply nested functions, which, *at that point* require stack space *as well*?

Comment: @Dario The trick is that tail-calls can eliminate stack space not only for _tail-recursive_ calls, but for any calls in a tail-call position. So, the call to `cont` will be also a tail-call - tail-calls are not limited to recursive calls!

Comment: Okay there we go, I understand that point. Is this elimination guaranteed to take place?

Comment: @Dario depends on compiler settings; in general, "yes" for release code and "no" for debug.  In VS, check `Application Settings` / `Build` / `Optimize code` and `Generate tail calls`.  For mono, use `fsc --optimize+ --tailcalls+` and `mono --optimize=all` or just `mono`.

Comment: Great to know. So in the end, to explain my confusion, the continuation trick does work, though for more complicated reasons and not in debug mode ;)

Answer (score 0):

The tricky thing with this question is that:

1. It's framed as a question about *general principles*;
2. But all the details about how it doesn't seem to work are inevitably going to be about *implementation details*.

Tail calls **can** be compiled so that no new frame is allocated on the stack or the heap.  The object code can simply create the callee's stack frame in-place with the same value of the stack pointer and transfer control unconditionally to its object code routine.

But I bolded the "can" because this is an **option** available to the language implementer.  Not all language implementations optimize all tail calls in all circumstances.

Somebody who knows F# is going to have to comment on the details of your case, but I can answer the question in your submission title:

> Does the continuation + tail recursion trick actually trade stack space for heap space?

The answer is that it entirely depends on your language implementation.  And in particular, implementations that try to provide tail-call optimization on more conventional VMs (like the Java VM) that weren't designed for it often provide incomplete TCO, with edge cases that don't work.